# Magento 2: How can create model without extends any class

Tags: magento2, model

I am creating a model but when I print class object showing blank? Why

```
namespace Pwa\Pay\Model;    
use \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface;    
class AbstractModel  {        
    protected $_appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    public function __construct(
        ScopeConfigInterface $appConfigScopeConfigInterface)
    {           
        $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface = $appConfigScopeConfigInterface;
    }
    public function hello(){
        echo get_class($this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface);
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you create an object?

Comment: $this->_appConfigScopeConfigInterface

Comment: I ask about AbstractModel? If you don't use ObjectManager dependencies will not be resolved.